# Project name under workspace Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I need to store the project names under a workspace into a list. I'm searching for a predefined function that returns all the project names in the workspace. Is in Eclipse such a function ? (plugin project)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the names in a list:

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

IProject [] projects = root.getProjects();

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

for (IProject project : projects) {
   names.add(project.getName());
}
```

This code must be run in a Eclipse plugin or headless app.